# How to add close button to delete slide from carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a button in carousel-inner so that I delete the slide from carousel like the picture. [image: carousel-inner]

I draw red color cross sign using pen of snapshot. However, I tried the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ltm</title>
<meta name="description" content="particles.js is a lightweight JavaScript library for creating particles.">
  <meta name="author" content="Vincent Garreau" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="sliderShow">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/slider2.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I add the button inside carousel? Please help.

Comment: need to provide the css code for a more plain  answer

Comment: @ashmna I edited it, Please see now and give me some suggestions